# Bash Script - Piping commands to echo

Tags: linux, bash

I have this command :

```
echo rm $(find "$SD" -type f -mtime "+$MT" -name "*.$TY" -print ) >> ${LOGFILE}
```

and it prints

```
rm /u01/oradata/logs/dwf_monitor_datafile.dbf.gz /u01/oradata/logs/dws_monitor_datafile.dbf.gz /u01/oradata/logs/dwd_monitor_datafile.dbf.gz
```

I want it to instead print

```
rm /u01/oradata/logs/dwf_monitor_datafile.dbf.gz 
rm /u01/oradata/logs/dws_monitor_datafile.dbf.gz 
rm /u01/oradata/logs/dwd_monitor_datafile.dbf.gz
```

How, thanks in adcance.

Answer (score 3):

If you actually want to delete the files, you should use find's `-delete` command.  If you are just trying to display nice-looking output, then try:

```
find "$SD" -type f -mtime "+$MT" -name "*.$TY" -exec echo rm {} \; >>${LOGFILE}
```

Comment: I am already doing that, I just want to generate this code for a manual delete later on. Something that you cut from the log and paste onto command line and run the actuals. The data may change thats why.

Comment: @user1918074 Did you try the `find` command in my answer for that?  In what way was its output not satisfactory for your purposes?